# Pointing My Domain Name to my VPS

Tags: ip, bind, vps

I have purchased a domain name and I asked them how to bind to my VPS. They answered, I should either use a control panel or create my own DNS server. So following guidelines about how to install BIND on Ubuntu 20.04, I did that. Registrar give two default nameservers for the domain name: cf21.hostingdunyam.net and cf212.hostingdunyam.net . And I created the zone file as :

```
$TTL    1d

@   IN  SOA cf21.hostingdunyam.net. shansal.zoho.com. (
                 10     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;

@   IN  A   80.253.246.157

@   IN  NS  cf21.hostingdunyam.net.
@   IN  NS  cf22.hostingdunyam.net.

www IN  A   80.253.246.157
```

So far I was not able to point that domain to ip address of my VPS. So I need an urgent support in here.

Answer (score 3):

1. We are not a support department.
2. If the Domain Registrar has provided you with Name Servers than use their Name Servers. Do not use your own Name Servers.
3. Log into your Domain Registrar account and set up your DNS records on their Name Servers.

Answer (score 1):

Your current configuration does not make sense.

You are hosting a DNS zone on your VPS and this zone contains two NS records that list to your registrar's DNS.

If your domain name does actually use that DNS zone hosted on the VPS, then it would not use the registrar's DNS.

If your domain name uses the registrar's DNS, then setting up a DNS on your VPS is useless.

If you really want to host your own DNS, you should use "glue records".

Answer (score 1):

If you use the registrar NS you should manage the DNS Record on Registrar zone.

In case, you can use your zone on VPS but you should add the glue record for your domain first and this can be add on your registrar side.

After glue added, you can change the NS record on your zone with your Glue NS.